# Plausibility of running Hoover Dam in a post-nuke world?

Tags: internal-consistency, post-apocalypse

So, in my world, the city that was once Las Vegas was rebuilt into a type of gang-ruled Sodom and Gomorrah, where the remnants of human civilization degrade themselves with prostitution, drugs, and slavery.

But, for me to have this, I have to have a way for the Vegans to have access to food and water, and the region is naturally a pretty into place. What I had planned was for the people of Vegas to grow corn, beans, squash, and cabbage with use of the mighty **Hoover Dam** as irrigation for the crop fields, using enslaved labor.

Here’s a question I had though: would there be any major implausibilities with running such a dam in a post-apocalyptic environment? If so, how could they get around them?

**Important Info**

-Vegas & Hoover Dam’s inhabitants have access to, let’s say, late 1800s to early 1900 manufacturing capability.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111671/discussion-on-question-by-dt-cooper-plausibility-of-running-hoover-dam-in-a-post).

Answer (score 10):

**Hoover Dam is a fine dam.  Use it for that.**

[image: Hoover Dam and vegas]

Long before there was hydroelectric power, people dammed waterways to create reservoirs.  That function of the Hoover Dam will work fine even as the hydroelectric machinery becomes nonfunctional.

There is nearly a square mile of flat desert in the wash leading up to Boulder Beach - circled.  You could irrigate that with canals from Lake Mead.  I worry the soil is not good but that can be remedied.

Farm using canal irrigation from the lake.  The dam is fine for making a lake, and probably will be for a long time to come.

---

You will need another solution for electricity.  I like the idea of using the dam for electricity but by adding waterwheels to the spillways and a notch cut in the top.  The waterwheels turn salvaged motors which generate electricity. Having the dam decorated by a motley bunch of motors turned by waterwheels of various sorts seems to me a good postapocalyptic look.

Answer (score 6):

- Was the dam hit?
  It would have made the list as a *counter-value* target during the Cold War days, but there are fewer weapons for any attacker these days. (Call it Russia? The Chinese have fewer missiles, not enough for a nuclear holocaust)
- Does the machinery last without maintenance?
  The electrical generators need regular [maintenance](https://www.power-technology.com/features/hoover-dam-maintenance-covid-19-hydro-generation-lake-mead-climate-change-post-apocalypse/), and the article says part of that is keeping the pipes clear. That should also affect irrigation use. Without the pipes, there is just overspill.
- How long does the dam itself last without maintenance?
  [This](https://zidbits.com/2013/05/how-long-will-the-hoover-dam-last/) one says thousands of years.

Comment: Your third bullet is something I didn't think about for my answer, but remember that while the concrete structure could theoretically last for thousands of years intact, the buildup of silt is a massive issue that won't take anywhere near that long. This was a fun question - hydroelectric dams are actually quite complex hummers.

Comment: The generating equipment might be tricky with early 1900s tech. Or not, since hydro-electric plants have operated since about 1895 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Niagara_Falls_hydroelectric_generating_plants#:~:text=It%20was%20the%20first%20large,N.Y.%2C%20and%20opened%20in%201961.  But clearing  the silt is as easy as cycling the fill of the dam a few times.

Answer (score 2):

**No, unless you can justify why no nukes fell anywhere near Las Vegas**

Hoover Dam, like all hydroelectric dams, uses turbines—big copper-wire-wound generators. Which makes them horrifically (and catastrophically) susceptible to the electromagnetic pulse of a nuclear detonation. It wouldn't even have to be close, but it will be close nonetheless due to Nellis Air Force Base and Area 51.

So, even if the dam mechanically survives (assuming a respectable-sized nuke, most of the water would be evaporated, but that would be naturally restored by Mother Nature), you're left with a bunch of heavy lumps of useless copper. In fact, since the turbines might not even  be able to turn anymore, you're also left with disbursing the hydraulic overburden via the spillways rather than through the power generating path — which might lead to early dam failure.

Kinda the only way around this is to explain why Nellis and Area 51 (and Las Vegas and Hoover Dam, for that matter) weren't obliterated in the apocalypse — which depends on why the nukes fell — which is story-based.  So, you need to create a non-military conflict that resulted in enough nuclear damage to leave Las Vegas alone well enough to justify the existence of an operating dam but not the existence of California's lush farming resources or anything-but-the-shortest-distance trucking. After all, Mad Max could make the run to San Diego in a couple of hours — and you need to explain a working tech like the dam but not trucking.

*Please note that My family was once "struck by lightning" in that a bolt hit within 1/4 mile of our house. It burned up electrical and phone wires, forcing me to do in-wall repairs. My point? A nuke that destroyed the turbines would also burn up main and minor powerlines in the whole region. You can't just fix the dam. You have to fix the distribution system, substations, local transformers, in-house wiring, and most of everything connected to the system throughout the entire region.*

**No, the skill set for maintenance is probably too broad**

Let's assume you have an acceptable story-reason to justify no nukes falling near Las Vegas — but your tech support (for reasons nobody knows, remember, no nukes fell hear the city) has reverted to more than 100 years ago. Is this sufficient technical skill to operate and continue to maintain the dam, its turbines, and the entire electrical distribution network?

Probably not. Oh, the skills might be enough (maybe, there's more modern tech in that distribution system than you realize, it's not just the turbines), but you don't have enough people or time to deal with it. Not without a working central government and stable economy.

**And that's the reason most post-apocalypse stories ignore the ugly details**

In the end, you can't have your cake (lawless prostitution, drugs, and gambling on the Las Vegas strip — which only *looks* that way today, it's an image, there's a TON of law going on in the background to maintain that image) and eat it, too (readily available food, sewage and sanitation, power...). Even if you hark back to the earliest agricultural days of Humanity, you had organized groups that were working together for the common good — not anarchistic lawlessness. And it's fairly difficult to explain how all that lawlessness exists when in the background there's an organized and controlled effort to feed everyone and keep the lights on.

So, as you write, remember that you can either:

1. Respect the fact that all technology of any kind requires stability, organization, education, and law to operate.

or...

2. You need to ignore #1 and just write your story.

Comment: 1) I suggest getting some more expert opinion on the idea that EMPs from normal nuclear weapons would permanently destroy generators &c.  2) Lack of trucking is easily explained by lack of oil.  But with Hoover Dam producing water & electricity, it'd be easy to run an electric rail line from the farming areas of the lower Colorado to Las Vegas.

Comment: EMPs ruin computers because they wipe the data.  Capacitors can overload and explode too which would be very bad for your power distribution network,  but generators will continue to function just fine; so, while the power grid may get wrecked, the power plant would not.   Also, a few feet of water or concrete can nullify an EMPs effects pretty quickly which is why we use them in nuclear power plants to contain radiation; so, even if an EMP could potentially harm the power plant by taking out its circuitry, it won't because the construction of the dam would block the EMP anyway.

Comment: It wouldn’t be too hard.  Say the military contractor that makes ABM systems is based in Las Vegas. I also agree that EMP isn’t a magic all-electricity-eraser; big burly mechanical electrical gear isn’t likely to be ruined. Electric rail is a natural; it was blowing up all over the place in the 1880s.

Comment: @Nosajimiki: EMPs also ruin computers because they're full of conducting traces that are a few tens of nanometers - that's billionths of a meter - wide, running at 3.5 volts or less.  The transmission lines leaving Hoover Dam run at up 500 kV, and have conductor diameters of around 100 mm.  Though it's not exactly the same thing, transmission lines are regularly struck by lightning, and have to be designed to cope with that: https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/effect-of-lightning-strike-on-electrical-lines

Comment: What odd comments... a moving electromagnetic field couples electricity onto a stationary wire, it's how power generators work (and high school electronics). Lightning strikes produce a fraction of the EMP a nuke would. Huh. The only comment that might make sense (maybe) is Nosajimiki's about the construction of the dam potentially blocking the EMP. Maybe. One assumption is that all that reinforcing iron rod is still there (despite studies that prove it rots away). Anyway, kids, I'll stick to my degree in electrical engineering. So many things will go wrong after a nuke that it's unbelievable.

Comment: @JBH: There were quite a few aboveground nuclear tests in the 1940s and 50s, which were recorded using electrical equipment, much of which survived.  Nuclear EMPs are not simple.  For one thing, they seem to depend on the altitude of the explosion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_electromagnetic_pulse

Comment: @jamesqf, equipment that was a long way away and expected to be outside the expected EMP effects and not containing hundreds of miles of wire. Per my answer, I'm assuming modern-age nukes dropping on Nellis AFB and Area 51 at best and Las Vegas itself at worst. I admit that I didn't sit down and do the math... but I suspect we've both jumped to conclusions that deserve better analysis.

Comment: @JBH: And Hoover Dam is quite a ways from any worthwhile targets. (Evidently Las Vegas itself didn't get nuked, otherwise there wouldn't be a post-attack community there.)  It's also down in a canyon, which would provide shielding since it's not line-of-sight to anything but a really high detonation.

Comment: @jamesqf Hoover dam is only 47 miles away from Nellis AFB, which is only twice the distance of the Tsar Bomba blast radius (22-34 miles). And that's assuming with more than 10,000 nuclear weapons in the the world that a major power-generating dam wouldn't be a primary target (unlikely). I might give you the canyon issue, but EM propagates into canyons much better than over mountains - which also exist between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Hydroelectric power, is overhead per watt, the most efficient method of producing electricity in the modern era.  Unlike fossil fuel or nuclear power plants, you don't need any complex mining & logistics since nature brings the potential energy to you.  And, unlike solar, it does not require any particularly hard to make parts like high purity silicon wafers to be able to repair it over time.  The only real downside is the huge initial investment in making a giant dam, but in this case, that part is taken care of for you already.

People have been building hydroelectric power plants since the 1880s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_Street_Plant; so, it will not be beyond your people's ability to understand and repair it. Capacity is also going to be pretty forgiving here. If a turbine breaks beyond repair, you have 16 other turbines to fall back on, and a whole pile of spare parts that you can now use to keep the other ones running when they themselves break, any single running turbine should have enough capacity to power a post apocalyptic civilization; so, even if you don't have manufacturing capabilities, it will still be a very long time before the dam becomes completely useless as a power source.

My only real criticism of Hoover Dam, is that this particular dam is unnecessarily huge for a post apocalypse civilization.  It's shear size, and the size of its moving parts are prohibitively large; so, unless your civilization has a population in the hundreds of thousands, a smaller more manageable dam may be preferable.

Comment: The post apoc city of Vegas is 99% less populous (population of 6,000 instead of 600k) so they don’t need that much electricity except for occasionally powering useful salvage.

Comment: Hoover dam can power 1.3 million modern homes.  Closer to 10 times that if you strip away most modern conveniences like Air Conditioning, Computers, etc. and just use it for lighting and the odd surviving household appliance.  At 6000 people, you could probably have all generators fail and just replace one with a much smaller improvised one.

Comment: note even after the generators fail, you could still use the shaft and turbine to run mills and mechanical pumps.

Answer (score 0):

No, they will be incapable of maintaining the generators.  In time something will wear out or break that is beyond their manufacturing, once that happens to each turbine (or perhaps a common failure point in the electrical system) it's no longer a hydroelectric dam.